# Is it possible to return data to the previous fragment when "FragmentManager.PopBackStack()" is called?

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing an app with `Xamarin.Android` in which I have a *root* activity including a `frame` for displaying different fragments. The *root* activity contains only navigation items. The whole content is shown in the different fragments.
One of the fragments is displaying a list of users. I want to provide a filter for this list. So I created a new fragment with all the filter options and a button which should apply all the filters on the previous "User-List-Fragment".
I display the "filter" fragment by adding a `frame` to my "User-List-Fragment" and load the "filter" fragment into it:

```
FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
   .AddToBackStack(null)
   .Replace(Resource.Id.members_filterFrame, new FilterFragment())
   .Commit();
```

To apply the filter I call

```
FragmentManager.PopBackStack();
```

in the "click event listener" of the "apply filter button", to display the "User-List-Fragment" again. But here it all comes to an sudden end because I don't know if or how I can populate the filter data back to my "User-List-Fragment".

This is a part of my `.axml` layout of the "User-List-Fragment". The `<FrameLayout />` overlays the `<ListView />` and gets only visible if the user presses the "filter button".

```
    .
    .
    .
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/members_listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="150dp" />

<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/members_filterFrame"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:visibility="gone" />
    .
    .
    .
```

**Question**
Is it possible to populate data from the `FilterFragment` back to the "User-List-Fragment" when calling `FragmentManager.PopBackStack();`?
If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass an `Action` to your `FilterFragment`.

When `OnDestroyView()` is  called you can invoke the `Action` and send back data.

---

**Example**

*First Fragment*

```
FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
.AddToBackStack(null)
.Replace(Resource.Id.members_filterFrame, new FilterFragment((parameter) => {
    // Do something with the given parameter
}))
.Commit();
```

*FilterFragment*

```
private Action<T> _onCompletionAction;
public FilterFragment(Action<T> onCompletionAction) 
{
    _onCompletionAction = onCompletionAction;
}

public override void OnDestroyView()
{
    base.OnResume();

    _onCompletionAction(parameter) // parameter could be a filter object.
}
```

Comment: This approach seems great. I'm still at the very beginning on becoming a C# developer so I didn't know about the `Action<T>` delegate. What I did in the meantime is, writing a EventHandler which holds a filter object and in the `OnDestroy()` method firing this event. Seems like a similar approach to yours. But yours works too so I'll give you the accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by firing an event with custom `EventArgs` after pressing the "apply filter button" in the `FilterFragment`:

```
Searched?.Invoke(this, new FilterAppliedEventArgs(FilterObject)); // fire search event
FragmentManager.PopBackStack();
```

The `FilterAppliedEventArgs` class looks like:

```
public class FilterAppliedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Filter FilterObject { get; set; }

    public FilterAppliedEventArgs(Filter filter)
    {
        this.FilterObject = filter;
    }
}
```

And registering the event in the "User-List-Fragment" before displaying the `FilterFragment` like this:

```
var filterFragment = new FilterFragment();
// get the filter attributes
filterFragment.Searched += (s, ea) =>
{
   var eventArgs = ea as FilterAppliedEventArgs;
   LoadFilteredMembers(eventArgs.FilterObject);
};

FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
   .AddToBackStack(null)
   .Replace(Resource.Id.members_filterFrame, filterFragment)
   .Commit();
```

---

The approach from @Pilatus seems very handy too. Both will work and I don't know which one is the better one.