# PopBackStack from fragment back to previous listview not data not visible anymore xamarin.android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have an activity en I start the frist fragment from that activity:

```
  var fragment1 = new Fragment1();
                var fragmentManager = SupportFragmentManager;
                var ft = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                    .SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.abc_fade_in, Resource.Animation.abc_fade_out)
                    .AddToBackStack(nameof(Fragment1))
                    .Add(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment1)
                    .Commit();
```

In Fragment1 I have a listview and I'm using an adapter to populate the list view. At first time load it works perfectly. I start Fragment2 from Fragment1 in with this code:

```
  var fragment2 = new Fragment2();
                var fragmentManager = SupportFragmentManager;
                var ft = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                    .SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.abc_fade_in, Resource.Animation.abc_fade_out)
                    .AddToBackStack(nameof(Fragment2))
                    .Add(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment2)
                    .Commit();
```

But when I navigate from Fragment1 to Fragment2 and call PopBackStack from Fragment2 to go back to Fragment1, the list view is totally blanc.

Here is my Fragment1 code:

```
 public class Fragment1 : Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            SetUpListView(view);
        }

        public void RefreshListView(List<Item> items)
        {
            if (View == null) return;

            var listView = View.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lv_items);
            var adapter = listView.Adapter as ItemsListViewAdapter;
            adapter.Items = items;
            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private void SetUpListView(View view)
        {
            var adapter = new ItemsListViewAdapter(Activity);
            var listView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lv_items);
            listView.Adapter = adapter;

            listView.ItemClick += ListView_ItemClick;
        }

        private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var fragment2 = new Fragment2();
            var fragmentManager = Activity.SupportFragmentManager;
            var ft = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            ft.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment2);
            ft.AddToBackStack(null);
            ft.Commit();
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.items, container, false);

        }
    }
```

Here is my Fragment 2:

```
public class Fragment2 : Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.shipments_search_menu, menu);
        var searchItem = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_search);
        var searchView = (SearchView)searchItem.ActionView;
        var expandListener = new OnActionExpandListener();
        expandListener.Collapse += (s, e) =>
        {
            Activity.SupportFragmentManager.PopBackStack();//here I must go back to Fragment1
        };

        searchItem.SetOnActionExpandListener(expandListener);
        searchView.QueryTextChange += SearchView_QueryTextChange;

        base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    private void SearchView_QueryTextChange(object sender, SearchView.QueryTextChangeEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        HasOptionsMenu = true;
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.search_shipments, container, false);


    }
}
```

Am i missing something? Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: You could try the way in the link below to invoke the Action and send back data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998523/is-it-possible-to-return-data-to-the-previous-fragment-when-fragmentmanager-pop

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT thank you for your answer. But my problem is that the list on Fragment1 just seems to disappear and I get a blanc fragment. So the search fragment (Fragment2) doesn't pass any parameters to Fragment1. But why do I get a blanc fragment? When I debug everything is still there my list of items on Fragment1 is still there and the listview is also still there.

Comment: But on your code, the Fragment1 seems okay. How do you navigate from Fragment2 to Fragment1? What do you mean the search Fragment?